# How does this site handle drug use

Tags: discussion

There was a question asked, where a user mentioned he was taking 'magic pills' that he got from a trainer. Obviously, these could be anabolics that he/she is unaware of - is it okay to point that out?

What is the site's stance on drug discussion?

Answer (score 5):

Something to consider with supplements and drugs is that what may be illegal where you are isn't illegal where the question-asker is, or maybe where the person providing the answer is. DMAA (as an example) is still legal in the United States, illegal in most western countries, but sometimes legal if not purchased for nutrition-supplementation.

Also, what's legal and illegal changes over time.

I don't think there's a current problem, in any regard, towards being honest about supplement or drug use. Even the term "drug" has different meanings in different countries at different times.

Taking a strong stance towards "illegal drugs" tends to be entirely subjective and most often incorrect.

Comment: Exactly, its legal in Brazil to buy, sell and use. We should not be restricting information based on fear of legality or some childish notion of "cheating".

Answer (score 4):

Personally I feel that the beauty of the structure here is to get expert answers to hard questions. Drugs shouldn't be excluded, and it's not the community's job to take a stance, especially if it's more politically or ethically driven rather than driven by curiosity or knowledge.

That being said, I understand the concern in creating a forum where it's all about supplementation, but let's not make policies based on something we don't know could happen.

Comment: Our help section on topics does not address drug use at all. I have seen on other sites that they do not forbid discussing such things, as they are not illegal in all places that SE might reach.

Answer (score 0):

We've discussed this before in this question.

- [Should we allow academic questions about drug use and other obviously poor health choices?](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/should-we-allow-academic-questions-about-drug-use-and-other-obviously-poor-healt)

The topic isn't explicitly prohibited, but many people have voiced their concerns about the usage of drugs and other substances. As Ivo Flipse stated (paraphrased below) in a [previous answer](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/241) on the topic (making reference to similar issues of "cheating" on other sites:

> We didn't want to build a reputation for encouraging something that
>   may or may not be illegal, so it was decided to stay safe rather than
>   sorry.
>
> ...
>
> However, I would hate to see this site turn into a place where we
>   advocate the best way to use drugs. If you want to improve your
>   performance, I'll gladly help you come up with a better training
>   program, but if you decide to take the easy way out... Good luck
>   elsewhere.

The upvotes on the answers align with this sentiment. Similarly, any [answers that are potentially dangerous](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/what-to-do-with-dangerous-answers) for the asker (and consequently everyone else) are also frowned upon as well. The community should be taking responsibility with the information it provides to others (as we do with people asking for medical advice).

Comment: Well it certainly isn't "the easy way out" (that's a very closed-minded, foolish, and naive stance) but thank you for the good answer!