# Are steroids on topic?

Tags: discussion

Are illegal steroids/SARMs and other substances which are sport related and illegal to ingest on topic? Can't see many questions on them.

Comment: In the light of the votes the two answers had received so far, I think you should unaccept the answer you had accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Generally this topic is not something that this community has encouraged or endorsed and to err on the side of caution. You can read through the meta questions below for reference.

[Should we allow academic questions about drug use and other obviously poor health choices?](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/should-we-allow-academic-questions-about-drug-use-and-other-obviously-poor-healt)

[What to do with dangerous answers?](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/what-to-do-with-dangerous-answers/)

[How does this site handle drug use](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/how-does-this-site-handle-drug-use)

Comment: In three links you provide, I don't see a clear consensus to exclude questions pertaining to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Though not strictly a answer to your question but i believe they should be on topic.

**Reason**

Those who are looking for easy way out needs to know reward vs risk.

**Background**

I believe the main cause of steroid abuse related complication is apathy of doctors.

When ever i tried consulting a doctor or health professional regarding steroids they always made me feel that one cycle will ensure my death or cancer or heart attack or what ever. But when i enter gym i see the pinning guys lifting and S**t this always used to leave me in lurch without info. Instead of explaining shutdown and difficult to keep gains they some how always use authority.

It will be great if people provide info and experience regarding them and prevent abuse and related complication.