# How should we handle questions about unsafe behavious?

Tags: discussion

Leading on from: [Should we allow academic questions about drug use and other obviously poor health choices?](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/should-we-allow-academic-questions-about-drug-use-and-other-obviously-poor-healt)

I feel that drug use was covered pretty well but poor health decisions was not.

A particular discussion point appeared today: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29376/maximum-weight-loss-in-72hrs

This specific question askes for advice on how to execute a known practice that, without medical support, can be very detrimental to health. There is also scope for people to give answers which could be detrimental to health.

Should we accept these questions about completing dangerous/unsafe practices with relation to exercise/diet as acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You can't regulate stupid.

All you can really do is provide an intelligent answer, with arguments against why what they are considering is a poor choice, but after that, can't do much.

And I'd rather allow the question and have good counterargument answers, to give them the information than to simply close the question and send them on their merry to try stuff on their own.